# Как реализовать данную функцию??Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

models.py:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=249)


class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=249)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student, through='Connect')

    

class Connect(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

функция view.py:

```
class CreateStudent(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    # …
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.save()
        for student in form.cleaned_data['name']:
            connect = Connect()
            connect.student = self.object
            connect.course = Course.objects.get(pk=1)
            connect.save()
        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

при создании нового `Student` создаться связь `Connect` c первым элементом `Course`

```
connect.course = Course.objects.get(pk=1)
```

как написать функцию(отдельную view.py) которая поможет выбрать какие значения `Course`при создании нового `Student` установить по умолчанию ?

---

**UPDATE**

Должна быть функция которая определяет к какие именно курсы мы выбираем по умолчанию в браузере . допустим у нас в базе есть 3 курса (Математика, Физика , Химия) сейчас добавляеться Математика так как она первая . А нужно сделать view которая отображает все курсы(названия) и пользователь выбирает какие именно курсы будут добавляться по умолчанию к следущим студентам . Допустим пользователь выбрал Физика , Химия . Тогда при создании нового студента добавляются связи с Физика , Химия а не с Математика

Comment: Распишите подробнее, чего хотите добиться

Comment: при создании нового Student создаться связь Connect  c первым  элементом Course, я хочу написать функцию во view при помощи которых я буду выбирать какие элементы Course  я  хочу что бы были по умолчанию при создании Student.

Comment: а как будете выбирать какой именно курс добавлять?

Comment: в браузере с уже существующими курсами (создаться отдельно)

Comment: опишите подробнее, каким образом будет происходить определение, какой курс назначается. Сейчас нельзя дать однозначный ответ на данный вопрос из-за недостатка информации. Будет ли это заполняться в админке, если да, то как узнаете что этому студенту нужен будет этот курс? Номер курса будет передаваться в урле? Храниться в настройках? Как?

Comment: Должна быть функция которая определяет к какие именно курсы мы выбираем по умолчанию в браузере . допустим у нас в базе есть 3 курса (Математика, Физика , Химия) сейчас добавляеться Математика так как она первая . А нужно сделать     view которая отображает все курсы(названия) и пользователь выбирает какие именно курсы будут добавляться по умолчанию к следущим студентам . Допустим  пользователь выбрал Физика , Химия . Тогда при создании нового студента добавляются связи с Физика , Химия а не с Математика .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так.

Создаете форму, добавляете поле курсы. После сохранения объекта студента. ставим ему выбранные курсы. Если курс не выбран - будет курс с наименьшим `id`.

PS: Привязываться к `id` равному 1 плохая идея, так как объект может быть удален. Тогда будет ошибка

```py
class FormAddStudent(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__' # Или че хотите

    courses = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Course.objects.all(), initial=Cource.objects.order_by('id').first())

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        obj.course_set.set(self.cleaned_data['courses'])
```

Comment: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__dict__'

Comment: `is_valid` применяли перед `save`? Если да, то сделайте еще и `form.clean()`

Comment: нет ,не применял